# Can you consume OData in an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, odata

Is it possible to consume OData in an SSRS report? If so how do I go about this?

I found the following which seemed quite hopeful, but nothing recently confirms for whether this is actually possible:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/559570/ssrs-should-be-able-to-use-odata-as-a-data-source

If this isn't yet implemented in SSRS 2008R2 are there any recommended workarounds?

Comment: Perhaps making a dataset of objects and pulling them in thru a web service returning odata. I have not done this but I am pretty sure it is a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, no. OData isn't a [supported data source for Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in current versions.

However SSRS can use ODBC data sources, so perhaps an [OData ODBC driver like this one](http://www.rssbus.com/odbc/?tabs=5) might be an alternative? I haven't tried this myself but it seems like a good option.